Arena Simulation Software can not generate Database
I'm using Arena simulator 16.2 (by Rockwell), in particular the "Arena training and Evaluation Mode" for students. The model can run, but there is no database or reports generated after the run. I am sure that I have not disabled run/setup/reports. Can not figure out why. Any suggestions?
The error message reads: Unable to locate report database for this model. Either the model has not yet been run, or the generation of the database (see Run/Setup/Reports) has been disabled.
